# How to determine if an Action parameter should be considered as 'Complex'?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm building an `IApplicationModelConvention` that needs to know if a Type is "complex".

My first attempt was to implement a helper method such as:

```
    public static bool IsComplex(this Type type)
    {
        Type[] handledTypes = new Type[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimeOffset), typeof(string) };

        return !type.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive && !handledTypes.Any(t => t.Equals(type));
    }
```

However this approach doesn't retrieve custom conversions added by the user.
(I don't even know how to implement these custom convertors)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up digging the aspnet core mvc sources.
In `ModelMetadata` a type is considered "complex" when there isn't any TypeConverter defined for string conversion:

```
 var isComplex = !TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(param.ParameterInfo.ParameterType).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string));
```